# Find and replace using files with regex

Tags: text-processing, awk

OK, let's suppose I've got **FileA.txt** that contains this:

```
string1, 3269
asdf, 8635
ghjk, 8534
foo, 4179
bar, 23490
```

I would like to use one or two text files (which ever case is easier) in which I can store this:

**FileB.txt**

```
string1 | 1string
bar | foo
```

"`|`" would be a separator, it wouldn't matter if it's has to be another file (1string and foo would be on *FileC.txt* if thats the case).

I would like to run a search and replace operation with the strings to search and replace in *FileB.txt* (and potentially a *FileC.txt*), so the result would be the following:

```
1string, 3269
asdf, 8635
ghjk, 8534
foo, 4179
foo, 23490
```

Any tools which I could use to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ a[$1]=$3; next }$1 in a{ $1=a[$1] }1' FileB.txt FS=',' OFS=',' FileA.txt
```

- `NR==FNR{ ... }` - processing the 1st input file i.e. `FileB.txt`:

  - `a[$1]=$3` - capturing each 3rd field value `$3` into array `a` using the 1st field `$1` as array index/key
  - `next` - jump to next record
- `$1 in a` - while processing the 2nd input file (i.e. `FileA.txt`), check if the 1st field value `$1` occurs in array `a` keys:

  - `$1=a[$1]` - replace with replacement value

---

The output:

```
1string,  3269
asdf, 8635
ghjk, 8534
foo, 4179
foo,  23490
```

Comment: Thanks, nice approach, but the commas got messed up in the replaced strings. In FileB, "|" would be just a separator so it could be anything, or even the whole right park could be another File to get the replace strings

Comment: @AdrianGraber, see my update

Answer (score 1):

Using `perl`, and pre-compiling the regular expressions for efficiency (not terribly important with only 2 search-and-replace patterns, but very useful if there are hundreds or thousands):

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

my %rep=();  # hash for storing search patterns with their replacements
my @rep=();  # array for storing search patterns in the order they were seen.

# first arg is the replacement file
my $replacements_file = shift;

open(REP,'<',$replacements_file) || die "Couldn't open $replacements_file: $!\n";
while(<REP>) {
  chomp;
  my ($s, $r) = split / \| /;

  my $search = qr/$s/; # precompile the regex

  $rep{$search} = $r;  # store the search regex and its replacement in a hash

  push @rep, $search;  # use an indexed array to remember the order the patterns
                       # were read in.
};
close(REP);

# main loop: process remaining args and/or stdin, apply each
# search and replace to every input line.

while(<>) {

  foreach my $s (@rep) {
    s/$s/$rep{$s}/;
  };

  print
}
```

Sample output:

```
$ ./replace.pl FileB.txt FileA.txt 
1string, 3269
asdf, 8635
ghjk, 8534
foo, 4179
foo, 23490
```

---

Warning: if the exact same search pattern appears more than once, only the last will be stored and used.  The easiest way to avoid that limitation is to to store the search patterns and their corresponding replacements in two separate arrays:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

my (@srch, @reps)=();

my $replacements_file = shift;

open(REP,'<',$replacements_file) || die "Couldn't open $replacements_file: $!\n";
my $count=0;
while(<REP>) {
  chomp;
  my ($s, $r) = split / \| /;

  $srch[$count] = qr/$s/;
  $reps[$count] = $r;
  $count++;
};
close(REP);
$count--;

while(<>) {
  foreach my $i (0..$count) {
    s/$srch[$i]/$reps[$i]/;
  };
  print
}
```

A hash isn't needed in this version, so I've used two arrays instead. 
 `@srch` to hold the search patterns, and `@reps` to hold the replacement strings.

Comment: note: it might be more useful to use `/search/replace/modifiers` as the format for `FileB.txt` - that way you could have individual modifiers for each search and replace pattern.   e.g. `/string1/1string/ig` to case-insensitively replace every "string1" with "1string" rather than just the first on each line.